# How to store outputs in a vector?

Tags: octave

I need to put the outputs of my function into a vector.

In fact my results seems like this:

```
ans= 

result 1

ans=

result2 

ans=

result3

......
```

I need that my result look  like this:

```
Vector= (result1
         result2
         result3
         ....)
```

The head of my function is like this:

```
function[keys]=generate()

    for k=1:257
      x= round(rand*9);
      vet = x*ones(1,16);
      i= round(rand*length(vet));
      i(i==0)=1;
      val= round(rand*257);
      vet(i)=val;
      keys=dec2hex (vet)
    endfor 

endfunction
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: show us the code to compute your `ans` please.

Comment: Your function is invalid. `keys` is never initialized and thus cannot be returned.

Comment: I edited it, thanks in advance.

Comment: My edited answer still applies.

Comment: `keys(k) = dec2hex(vet)` where keys is your vector of answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would omit the for loop and you should use `randi` if you want to generate random integers, for example for indexing. And I guess you want to split generating of keys and converting them to hex because the hex format is for visualisation. At the end I guess this question suffers from the [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

```
function keys = generate ()

  key_cnt = 5;
  key_offset = 9;
  key_length = 16;

  keys = ones (1, key_length) .* randi (key_offset + 1, key_cnt, 1) - 1;
  val = randi (2 ** 8, key_cnt, 1) - 1;
  i = randi (key_length, key_cnt, 1);
  ind = sub2ind ([key_cnt, key_length], 1:key_cnt, i');
  keys (ind) = val;

endfunction

function ret = hex_keys (k)

  ## convert keys to hex string
  for i = 1:rows (k)
    ret(i, :) = [sprintf("%02X ",k(i,1:15)), sprintf("%02X",k(i,16))];
  endfor

endfunction


k = generate ();
hex_keys (k)
```

gives

```
00 00 00 2A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 03 C7 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03
07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 A7 07 07 07
03 03 03 03 03 03 03 8F 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03
03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 D0 03 03 03 03 03 03
```

Of course increase key_cnt to 257 if you are finished with testing.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy for your help, However  what about the problem of XY , I think that I don't have a good english to explain my goal, That is it. I  am rying to improve it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is, generally speaking, a very vague question.

If the function you are calling returns multiple things you can capture them in a vector like so:

```
[a, b, c] = myFunc()
```

If you are calling multiple functions each storing one thing you could do something like this:

```
vec = []
a = myFunc1()
vec = [vec a]
a = myFunc2()
vec = [vec a]
etc...
```

or shorter:

```
vec = [myFunc1() myFunc2() ... ]
```

---

It seems as though the `ans` output you're seeing is a result of the lack of a semi-colon on the line:

```
dec2hex(vet)
```

You should save that output into a vector and return that:

```
function[keys]=generate()
  keys = [];
  for k=1:257
   x= round(rand*9);
   vet = x*ones(1,16);
   i= round(rand*length(vet));
   i(i==0)=1;
   val= round(rand*257);
   vet(i)=val;
   keys = [keys dec2hex(vet)];
 endfor % endfor for octave
endfunction
```

Comment: I edit my question and i put the function. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sur please about this instruction keys = [keys dec2hex (vet)];???

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however, i need that my results are  separated by a comma; i will use this result in a loop for

Comment: I think that ur  solution is the best one but result are written verticallyhow do I put it horizontally, thanks in advance.

Comment: `keys = generate();`
`keys = keys';`

Comment: Also, if you think my solution is the best one you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

very likely you can wrap your statement to compute `ans` into either `horzcat` or `vertcat` to achieve what you want.